# Cannot use filter columns from materialized view log on Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to create an aggregate Materialized View:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS
    NOLOGGING
    BUILD IMMEDIATE 
    REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
    AS 
        SELECT AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID, MAX(AD.VERNUM) AS MAX_VERNUM, MIN(AD.DEFVERN) AS MAX_DEFVERN
        FROM   CSTST.MV_LLATTRDATA_PARTITIONED_TEST AD, DTREECORE DT
        WHERE AD.ID = DT.DATAID
        GROUP BY AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID;
```

I don't understand the error. I have created a MV Log file for both the LLATTRDATA time and the DTREECORE table

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON CSTST.DTREECORE (and LLATTR) WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

Error:

> Error report - ORA-12033: cannot use filter columns from materialized
>   view log on "CSTST"."DTREECORE"
>   12033. 0000 -  "cannot use filter columns from materialized view log on \"%s\".\"%s\""
>
> Cause:    The materialized view log either did not have filter columns
>              logged, or the timestamp associated with the filter columns was
>              more recent than the last refresh time.
>
> Action:   A complete refresh is required before the next fast refresh.
>              Add filter columns to the materialized view log, if required.

DTREECORE DDL:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "CSTST"."DTREECORE"
 PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 30 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CSPRD" 
  WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

LLATTRCORE DDL:

```
  CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON "CSTST"."LLATTRDATA"
 PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 30 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "CSPRD" 
  WITH ROWID INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

I've tried adding the LLATTRCORE View Log to Include New Values but I'm running into a permission issue

Comment: Please edit your question to show the full DDL for all the objects, and the full error you get. That seems to be a fragment of the description from an ORA-12033 error, but not sure.

Comment: @AlexPoole hey sorry about that, added more details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The documentation shows ["Restrictions on Fast Refresh on Materialized Views with Aggregates"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-932B8CD4-BF60-419A-9202-8A9FD5D24024):

> All tables in the materialized view must have materialized view logs, and the materialized view logs must:
>
> - Contain all columns from the table referenced in the materialized view.
> - Specify with ROWID and INCLUDING NEW VALUES.
> - Specify the SEQUENCE clause if the table is expected to have a mix of inserts/direct-loads, deletes, and updates.

You need to include all of the columns used in your MV in the logs, e.g.:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON MV_LLATTRDATA_PARTITIONED_TEST
WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(ID, DEFID, ATTRID, VERNUM, DEFVERN) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON DTREECORE
WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(DATAID) INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

Then you can create the MV:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS
    NOLOGGING
    BUILD IMMEDIATE 
    REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
    ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
    AS 
        SELECT AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID, MAX(AD.VERNUM) AS MAX_VERNUM, MIN(AD.DEFVERN) AS MAX_DEFVERN
        FROM   MV_LLATTRDATA_PARTITIONED_TEST AD, DTREECORE DT
        WHERE AD.ID = DT.DATAID
        GROUP BY AD.DEFID, AD.ATTRID;

Materialized view MV_LLATTRDATA_MAX_VERSIONS created.
```

Not the most helpful error message...

Comment: I didn't realize I had to create a MV Log on the first MV as well, I didn't have that at first, just the Base Table. Good to know.