# Create matview refresh fast on commit fails with ORA-12033

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

Oracle Database - Standard Edition - Version 12.1.0.2.0, platform Windows 64-bit

**I'm getting ora-12033 error while trying to create mview, all necessary columns are already included in the mview log. When i'm trying to do same thing on 11g version it works, but 12c throwing ora error.**

Please help me solve this problem or provide links that may help.

Here is code:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON contract_details
with rowid (count, contract_id) including new values;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW m_contract_sum
refresh fast on commit
as
select d.contract_id as contract_id,
       count(*) as count_grp,
       count(d.count) as cnt_count,
       sum(d.count) as sm_count
  from contract_details d
 group by d.contract_id;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no problem with your syntax unless you replace `count` with `"count"` which's reserved keyword without quotes.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan thanks for reply, but with name and quotes is everything okey, I also don't see problems. While searching for a solution, I found that this could be related with switched on extended statistics on that table. Do you know something about this or have a deal?

Comment: you're welcome. I think this might be such a nice answer link fo your case : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813870/cannot-use-filter-columns-from-materialized-view-log-on-table

Answer (score 1):

There might be a problem with extended stats, which are automatically created to gather stats on group of columns. 
You can verify it by executing following query:

```
SELECT column_name, data_default, virtual_column, hidden_column 
  FROM dba_tab_cols 
 WHERE table_name = 'CONTRACT_DETAILS' AND hidden_column = 'YES';
```

If this is a case, you need to drop the stats (using `dbms_stats.drop_extended_stats`) before (re-)creating materialized view.
e.g.

```
BEGIN
   dbms_stats.drop_extended_stats('master', 'contract_details', '(x, y)');
END;
/
```

Afterwards you probably would like to gather the stats again, by using

```
BEGIN
   dbms_stats.create_extended_stats('master', 'contract_details', '(x, y)')
END;
/
```